# Prop is Not Defined VueJS

Tags: vuejs2

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting an uncheckable is undefined in my js file when I'm telling it that its a prop.

```
<checklist :uncheckable="true" type="permit" project="{{ $roofingProject->id }}"></checklist>
```

Component:

```
<input :disabled="isDisabled(item)" type="checkbox" v-model="item.isCompleted" v-on:change="completeChecklistItem(index, item)" /> <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o text-success" aria-hidden="true" v-if="item.isCompleted"></i><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o text-danger" aria-hidden="true" v-else></i> <span>{{ item.content }}</span>


<script>
module.exports = {
    http: {
        headers: {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken
        }
    },
    props: ['type', 'project', 'uncheckable'],
    data: function(){
        return { items: [] };
    },
    methods: {
        isDisabled: function (item) {
            return !uncheckable && item.isCompleted
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use `this` inside your `isDisabled(){}` method

change

```
return !uncheckable && item.isCompleted
```

to

```
return !this.uncheckable && item.isCompleted
```